# How to pass multiple post parameters to web api using angular typescript

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, typescript

I would like to pass multiple values to the following web api using angularjs typescript.

```
// POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value1, [FromBody]string value2)
        {
        }
```

I would like to call the above method something like this

```
$http.post('api/values', ???)
```

As I need to do some validations on the page by passing multiple parameters to the database.
I also tried with GET instead of post but didn't work for me.

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you.
Hari C

Answer (score 1):

You can't read multiple values "FromBody". Instead you should define "Request" class with all needed parameters:

```
    public class Request
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; } 
        public string Value2 { get; set; } 
    }

    //POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]Request request)
    {
    }
```

And then like Aran said you can go this way

```
$http.post('api/values', {Value1:"foo", Value2:"bar"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` property (the second argument of `$http.post`) to pass your parameters:

```
$http.post('api/values', {x:"foo", y:"bar"});
```